# Read a input from Scanner to Array of Strings in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get the input from scanner and assign the value into a String array And the loop has to run for 3 times abut it's taking only two inputs. can anyone please explain why this is not taking 3 inputs and displaying the same.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DimentionalArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = sc.nextInt(); // ex, if size is 3 
        String[] str = new String[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            str[i] = sc.nextLine(); 
        }
        Arrays.stream(str).forEach(e -> {System.out.println(e);});
    }
}
```

For example.
my inputs are

```
3 //size
1 2 // 1st input 
3 4 //2nd input 
4 5 // 3rd input
```

but it's not reading the input and its getting closed after reading the 2nd input(3 4).
Can anyone please explain why is this not reading the third element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
sc.nextLine();
```

after the int size = sc.nextInt();